# Enable DNS over HTTPS (DoH) when visiting a specific domain

Tags: dns, dns-over-https

I am totally new with this new protocol that is already available in latest Firefox browser but I can not manage it to work on Chrome browser at least in a Windows PC. Now I totally had no idea where to put this question in SO so please understand.

Can I enable DoH feature automatically on Firefox or Chrome in Windows by just visiting a site?
If can not, then can I create a batch script or desktop app instead that will patch/enable DoH to the said browsers?

Answer (score -1):

You can enable DNS over HTTPS (DoH) for Google Chrome like this:

```
1) Type this into address(URL) bar of Google Chrome: chrome://flags/#dns-over-https
2) You will see "Secure DNS lookups" in the opened tab: Click and change from the select box: Enabled/Disabled or Default 
3) Done
```